# Sending message to a number stored as String in Arduino

Tags: arduino, at-command, sim900

I am using SIM900 with arduino mega and have to send a message to a specific number I store in a variable, using AT commands. I am storing the number as a String but it gives an error. Below are the relevant lines of code:

```
String number1 = "923360234233";
Serial1.write("AT+CMGS=\"" + number1 + "\"");
```

It gives the following error.

```
no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::write(StringSumHelper&)'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `write` can be used only for C-strings `char *`, `uint8_t *` and similar buffers.

However if you've used string addition: `const char *` + `String` + `const char *` you'll get `StringSumHelper` which is not supported by `write`.

So you can use:

```
Serial1.print("AT+CMGS=\"" + number1 + "\"");
```

or

```
Serial.write(("AT+CMGS=\"" + number1 + "\"").c_str());
```

or

```
Serial1.write("AT+CMGS=\"");
Serial.print(number1);
Serial.write("\"");
```

Comment: But it still does not work. I am unable to receive text on my phone.

Comment: Well, you asked why that part of code can't be compiled and that's solved. And attached code is incomplete. So how should I know why it's not sending anything. At least take a look [here](https://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/at-cmgs-text-mode/).

Comment: Right! My apologies. 
If I upload the code, will you be able to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Well, new question would be better.

Comment: Worked for SIM808.